# woocommerce shows payment method two times after update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout

I updated WooCommerce to the latest version and now - in the checkout - the available payment methods are shown two times right after eachother as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

In my WooCommerce files I found that the review-order.php file generate this page. I found the file here: /wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/woocommerce/checkout

Please note that there is some custom code in there - this might be the cause of this?

I know that everything within the tag  is generating the payment method view but I cant figure out why it generates two of them.

I apologize for the long code. I was not sure what to include or exclude.

I hope you are able to help me out!

**The review-order.php file:**

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$available_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
?>
<div id="order_review" class="order_review">
  <h2 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e('Betalingsoversigt', 'academy'); ?></h2>
<table class="shop_table" style="display:block;">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents');

        if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->get_cart()) > 0) :
            foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $values) :
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ($_product->exists() && $values['quantity'] > 0) :
                    echo '
                            <tr class="' . esc_attr(apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_table_item_class', 'checkout_table_item', $values, $item_id)) . '">
                                <td class="product-name">' . $_product->get_title() . ' <strong class="product-quantity">&times; ' . $values['quantity'] . '</strong>' . $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data($values) . '</td>
                                <td class="product-total">' . apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_item_subtotal', $woocommerce->cart->get_product_subtotal($_product, $values['quantity']), $values, $item_id) . '</td>
                            </tr>';
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;

        do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents');
        ?>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php _e('Subtotal', 'academy'); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax()) : ?>
            <tr class="discount">
                <th><?php _e('Rabat', 'academy'); ?></th>
                <td>-<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_before_tax(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($woocommerce->cart->needs_shipping() && $woocommerce->cart->show_shipping()) : ?>
            <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping'); ?>
            <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php _e('Levering', 'academy'); ?></th>
                <td><?php woocommerce_get_template('cart/shipping-methods.php', array('available_methods' => $available_methods)); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_fees() as $fee) : ?>
            <tr class="fee fee-<?php echo $fee->id ?>">
                <th><?php echo $fee->name ?></th>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if ($woocommerce->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl')
                        echo woocommerce_price($fee->amount);
                    else
                        echo woocommerce_price($fee->amount + $fee->tax);
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php
        if ($woocommerce->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl') {

            $taxes = $woocommerce->cart->get_taxes();
            if (sizeof($taxes) > 0) {

                $has_compound_tax = false;

                foreach ($taxes as $key => $tax) {
                    if ($woocommerce->cart->tax->is_compound($key)) {
                        $has_compound_tax = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <th><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->tax->get_rate_label($key); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $tax; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }

                if ($has_compound_tax) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="order-subtotal">
                        <th><?php _e('Subtotal', 'academy'); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(true); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }

                foreach ($taxes as $key => $tax) {
                    if (!$woocommerce->cart->tax->is_compound($key))
                        continue;
                    ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <th><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->tax->get_rate_label($key); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $tax; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            } elseif ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_tax()) {
                ?>
                <tr class="tax">
                    <th><?php _e('Tax', 'academy'); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_tax(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_after_tax()) : ?>
            <tr class="discount">
                <th><?php _e('Order Discount', 'academy'); ?></th>
                <td>-<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_discounts_after_tax(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total'); ?>
        <tr class="total">
            <th><strong><?php _e('Total', 'academy'); ?></strong></th>
            <td>
                <strong><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?></strong>
                <?php
                if ($woocommerce->cart->tax_display_cart == 'incl') {
                    $tax_string_array = array();
                    $taxes = $woocommerce->cart->get_formatted_taxes();

                    if (sizeof($taxes) > 0) {
                        foreach ($taxes as $key => $tax) {
                            $tax_string_array[] = sprintf('%s %s', $tax, $woocommerce->cart->tax->get_rate_label($key));
                        }
                    } elseif ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_tax()) {
                        $tax_string_array[] = sprintf('%s tax', $tax);
                    }

                    if (!empty($tax_string_array)) {
                        ?><small class="includes_tax"><?php printf(__('(Includes %s)', 'academy'), implode(', ', $tax_string_array)); ?></small><?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total'); ?>
    </tfoot>

</table> 

</div>

<div id="payment">
   <div id="price"><?php ?></div>
    <?php
    global $current_user;
    $current_user_role = get_user_meta($current_user->data->ID, 'user_role');
    ?>
    <?php if ($woocommerce->cart->needs_payment()) : ?>
        <div class="accordion toggles-wrap payment-listing">
            <?php
            $available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
            if ($available_gateways) :
                $counter = 0;
                if (sizeof($available_gateways)) :
                    $custom_gateway = get_option('woocommerce_default_gateway');
                    if ($current_user_role[0] == 'private_person') {
                        $custom_gateway = 'epay_dk';
                    }
                    if ($current_user_role[0] == 'driving_school_student') {
                        $custom_gateway = 'cod';
                    }
                    if ($current_user_role[0] == 'company') {
                        $custom_gateway = 'cod';
                    }

                    $default_gateway = $custom_gateway;
                    if (isset($_SESSION['_chosen_payment_method']) && isset($available_gateways[$_SESSION['_chosen_payment_method']])) :
                        $available_gateways[$_SESSION['_chosen_payment_method']]->set_current();
                    elseif (isset($available_gateways[$default_gateway])) :
                        $available_gateways[$default_gateway]->set_current();
                    else :
                        current($available_gateways)->set_current();
                    endif;
                endif;
                foreach ($available_gateways as $gateway) :
                    ?> 
                    <div class="toggle-container <?php if ($gateway->get_title() == $payment_def) echo 'expanded'; ?>" >

                        <label for="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" class="toggle-title"><h5 class="nomargin"><?php echo $gateway->get_title(); ?></h5></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" class="hidden" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr($gateway->id); ?>" <?php if ($gateway->chosen) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />                          
                        <?php if ($gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description()) : ?>
                            <div class="toggle-content payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>"><?php $gateway->payment_fields(); ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>         
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $counter++;
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="form-row place-order">
        <?php $woocommerce->nonce_field('process_checkout') ?>  
        <?php if (woocommerce_get_page_id('terms') > 0) : ?>
            <div class="terms">
                <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked(isset($_POST['terms']), true); ?> id="terms" />
                <label for="terms" class="checkbox"><?php _e('Jeg accepterer', 'academy'); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('terms'))); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e('Reddernes Vilkår', 'academy'); ?></a></label>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit'); ?>
        <input type="submit" class="button alt place-order-button" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="<?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_order_button_text', __('Betal nu', 'academy')); ?>" />
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_submit'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<style>.woocommerce-checkout .checkout .order_review table.shop_table td{ width: 100%;}#payment #price .total p{ text-align: right;}</style>
```

Comment: Not a reason for the bug, but what is the reason behind `$counter`? Debugging only?

Comment: If you're a `driving_school_student` do you get the `epay_dk` & the `cod` payment gateways?

Comment: Hi Dez - Yes, the counter is for debugging. If you are a driving school student, you get the COD as well as the ePay. If this isnt the reason for the bug do you then know where I should search for the bug?

Comment: Had this issue as well. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277788/woocommerce-shows-two-sets-of-all-payment-methods/28692731#28692731