# WooCommerce shows two sets of all payment methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After a long time I finally updated WooCommerce with the latest update.
Now, in the checkout, it shows two sets of all the available payment methods.

[image]

I have been looking at the file review_order.php in the woocommerce folder but I couldnt find a solution there.
Do any of you know what the error might be and where I should look for the bug?

I appreciate all the information you can give me!

FYI: I can´t contact WooThemes since the solution is bought from many years ago and I dont have the license.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. **You need to update the template overwriting files in your theme.**

My issue was that the template files in `woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php` was different from the one that was overwriting it in my theme.

The theme I used had some pre-packaged templates and all I had to do was copy the code from the new WooCommerce version over to the theme.

It was clear when you look at the file header that there was updates. I was on 2.1.3 and the latest that comes with the plugin is 2.3.0.

WooCommerce warns you about out dated template files all the time... but the work involved updating them sucks.

Good Luck!